# OpenGL ES texture problem, 4 duplicate columns and horizontal lines (Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, rgb, textures

I have a buffer of RGB (or RGBA) texture image, and I want to display it on my Android device with the following code. I use OpenGL from NDK.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             256,
             256,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             this->pBuffer);
```

I have also set the PixelFormat from the Java side with:

```
this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
```

The image is displayed but there are four columns (identical and contains recognizable parts of the original image) and there are horizontal lines all over the image.

What can be the problem?

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

How it looks with my code:

[image: How it looks with my code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the image size is not 256 by 256, but maybe about 150 pixels wide. Your texture has to be a power of 2 big, but if you need to upload a smaller texture you can use [glTexSubImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml):

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  /* target */
            0,      /* level */
            0,      /* xoffset */
            0,      /* yoffset */
            150,        /* width */
            256,        /* height */
            GL_RGBA,    /* format */
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,   /* type */
            this->pBuffer); /* data */
```

In the initial glTexImage2D call, just pass NULL instead of the pixel buffer. Try something like this, see if it makes a difference.

If you're using glDrawTexiOES to draw the texture, then to crop the smaller texture use GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES:

```
int rect[4] = {0, imageHeight, imageWidth, -imageHeight};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, rect);
glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I managed to display the image correctly. But now the image is not scaled to the width of the display. I use the glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight). Is this the correct way?

Comment: @Ertan D. I've edited the answer with more info, but if your window area is 256x256 and the image is not that same aspect ratio (1:1) it may look "wrong" - the only fix would be to change the aspect ratio of the image or clip it in a different way (eg. lose some of the image greater than a certain height)

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you! I was setting the GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES to the texture size, not the actual image size. That was my problem. Now it's working exactly like I want it to.