# OpenGL ES draw camera preview, extra horizontal lines only for some image size

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, textures, lines

I have RGB buffer that I draw on texture which placed to GLSurfaceView.
The size of RGB image is the same as the size of GLSurfaceView.

Image of size 1024x600 (16:9, full screen) is drawn correctly. But image of size 800x600 (4:3) is drawn with horizontal lines as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837928/opengl-es-texture-problem-4-duplicate-columns-and-horizontal-lines-android) but without additional columns.

Here is the code how I draw images:
*SurfaceView code*

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }

    currHalfWidth = width/2;
    currHalfHeight = height/2;

    cameraDist = (float)(currHalfHeight / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(45.0f / 2.0f)));

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 2000.0f);
    //GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 0.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix

    cameraPreview.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
}
```

*CameraPreview code*

```
public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height)
{
    surfaceWidth = width;
    surfaceHeight = height;
    out = new byte[width*height*2];

    vertexBuffer.clear();

    vertices = new float[]{ 
            -height/2.0f, -width/2.0f, 0.0f, //Bottom Left
            height/2.0f, -width/2.0f, 0.0f,     //Bottom Right
            -height/2.0f, width/2.0f, 0.0f,     //Top Left
            height/2.0f, width/2.0f, 0.0f   //Top Right
                            };
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl, byte[] yuv_data, Context context) {

    if(yuv_data != null && context != null)
        this.loadGLTexture(gl, yuv_data, context);


    // bind the previously generated texture        
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);       

    // Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW); 

    // Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer); 

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);        

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, byte[] yuv_data, Context context) {      


    Camera.Parameters params = MainScreen.getCameraParameters();
    int imageWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
    int imageHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;           

    textureWidth = 512;
    textureHeight = 512;        

    NativeConverter.convertPreview(yuv_data, out, imageWidth, imageHeight, textureWidth, textureHeight);        

    //...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);  

    //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);             

    gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(out));      
}
```

**UPD**: Problems solved! It wasn't openGL issue, but input 'yuv_data' buffer was already corrupted.

Comment: What is the NativeConverter doing exactly? I assume it converts yuv data to rgb and writes it to "out". Are the width and height of "out" same as the camera preview width and height? And why is the size of "out" width*height*2 ?

Comment: You'r right, it converts yuv (NV21) data to rgb. Size of 'out' depends on bpp, in my case bpp = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be completely certain without knowing what NativeConverter is doing, but this sounds very much like a pixel unpack alignment issue.

By default OpenGL expects all texture rows to be a multiple of 4 bytes. You can get into problems when you use byte-per-pixel values other than 4 with non-power-of-two image sizes, both of which you seem to be using.

If you don't want to align your texture rows to 4 byte boundaries, then you tell OpenGL that they are not aligned to 4-byte boundaries by setting 
`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before uploading your texture.

Comment: I used to try GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, no effect. Now I'm checking if 'out' buffer is correct, maybe bug is in NativeConverter.